# How to add css file through url of page

Tags: css

my point is to load css file via URL like this:

www.somepage.com/?loadcss=cutomfile.css

Its for testing purposes, vhere I need to test multiple css files and dont want to change source code everytime.

Cant find any solution (i wish it works without javascript, but is that possible?).

Thanks for some ideas.

Comment: You could get the params in `php` and include the file in the backend.

Comment: Is he actually using PHP?

Comment: Are you using any back-end language?

Answer (score 0):

**If** you happen to be using PHP which I doubt, then here's an easy solution.

1. get the style sheet from the URL with `$CSSfile = $_GET["loadcss"]`
2. then just do `echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$CSSfile.'">';`

This will take the parameter set in your URL (1) and then add it in the `href` of a link tag that will pull the desired file in.